# node.js, css validation, w3c banned me?

Tags: css, node.js, gulp, w3c-validation

I apologize in advance for what I write through a translator, I am very bad at English.

I was faced with the following problem: I need to perform validation css files. To this end, I decided to use the NPM package [w3c-css](https://github.com/gchudnov/w3c-css), first it worked, but then start giving "connected etimedout", in the course of research, I noticed that through the browser and the validator stops working.

Sniffer log at start of my script: [link](http://rghost.ru/private/6bCRYMz6l/3c044948a8f73a071d0bb7c442e21b1e) (<10 rep :( )

My code:

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
  gulp.src('dev/sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(through2.obj(function(file, enc, cb){
      w3c_css.validate({text: file.contents.toString('utf8')}, function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
          // an error happened
          console.error(err);
        } else {
          // validation errors
          console.log('validation errors', data.errors);

          // validation warnings
          console.log('validation warnings', data.warnings);
        }

      });
      cb(null, file);
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
});
```

What is the reason? It must be some mistake, or I block due to too frequent requests and it does not change? Maybe there is some other way to check the css files?

**Thx!**

Comment: It seems that this package was designed to be runned from time to time, like in a test, not everytime you change your files. You could check [the readme from this another W3C validator](https://github.com/thomasdavis/w3cjs)

Answer (score 0):

From the "[About](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/about.html#api)" page of the CSS validation service of the W3C:

> *Can I build an application upon this validator? Is there an API?*
>   Yes, and yes. The CSS Validator has a (RESTful) SOAP interface which should make it reasonably easy to build applications (Web or otherwise) upon it. **Good manners and respectful usage of shared resources are of course customary: make sure your applications sleep() between calls to the validator, or install and run your own instance of the validator**.

So yes, it seems you have been banned.

I don't know how to make a gulp task to be called from time to time. You may [mount a local version of the CSS Validator webservice](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/DOWNLOAD.html) and [editing the w3c-css package](https://github.com/gchudnov/w3c-css/blob/master/lib/css-validator.js) to point to your own server.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your script will sleep for at least 1 second between requests.
From the [manual](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/manual.html):

> Note: If you wish to call the validator programmatically for a batch
>   of    documents, please make sure that your script will sleep for at
>   least 1 second between requests. The CSS Validation service is a free,
>   public service for all, your respect is appreciated. thanks.

To validate multiple links, use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachseriesarr-iterator-callback) + [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) or any related way to pause between the requests:

```
'use strict';

var async = require('async');
var validator = require('w3c-css');

var hrefs = [
    'http://google.com',
    'https://developer.mozilla.org',
    'http://www.microsoft.com/'];

async.eachSeries(hrefs, function(href, next) {
  validator.validate(href, function(err, data) {
    // { process err, data.errors & data.warnings }

    // sleep for 1.5 seconds between the requests
    setTimeout(function() { next(err); }, 1500); 
  });
}, function(err) {
  if(err) {
    console.log('Failed to process an url', err);
  } else {
    console.log('All urls have been processed successfully');
  }
});
```

EDIT:

To mitigate this issue:

- Added some [comments](https://github.com/gchudnov/w3c-css#note) and an [example](https://github.com/gchudnov/w3c-css/blob/master/examples/validate-multiple.js).
- Placed `setTimeout` right into the [gulp-w3c-css plugin](https://github.com/gchudnov/gulp-w3c-css/blob/master/index.js#L32).